# How to get drag and drop functionality in asp.net 4.0 using AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, user-interface

I want to have a drag and drop functionality in my web-page. The web-page is having two tables A and B. Both tables are having 2 columns and 5 rows. The table A is having div section inside the cells and this div contains some information in the form of labels and textboxes.

Now we want to enable user to pick the div from the table A and drag it to table B and drop it there. On doing so the div would move from table A to table B into the cell where it was dropped.

How to achieve this feature in Asp.net 4.0 using AJAX or jquery.

Kindly help

Comment: i think you need also to save state after dragging (in database or cookies), i'm doing brain storming and don't have solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hiya In Jquery **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jT7wK/ && Another **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/56ua2/ (WHen you drag and drop the rows you will see the alerts - I am pretty sure this will come handy)

*Good API link:* http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

This link might come handy: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/droppable-between-two-tables

Hope this help, plz let me know if I missed anything, cheers!

**Jquery code**

```
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "DropThings", its similar to "iGoogle"

[Codeplex](http://dropthings.codeplex.com/)

[Working sample](http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/)

Answer (score 0):

DragPanel (Ajax toolkit) Description:

The DragPanel extender allows users to easily add "draggability" to their controls. The DragPanel targets any ASP.NET Panel and takes an additional parameter that signifies the control to use as the "drag handle". Once initialized, the user can freely drag the panel around the web page using the drag handle.

[Ajax toolkit drag panel](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DragPanel/DragPanel.aspx)

Using jQuery UI (see the demo):

[Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

[Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)